# mac M1 git pull shows Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib One of the two will be used

Tags: git, macos, apple-m1

`git pull` generates this message on osx 11.4 Apple Silicon M1

```
scottstensland@sjuuuukt: ~/src/github.com/foo/bar/build $ git pull
objc[1017]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20aa0ac10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113bd02b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1017]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20aa0ac60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113bd0308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 5 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), 426 bytes | 106.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:foo/bar
   10a27ff9b..b26b293b9  master     -> origin/master
Already up to date.
```

this is not under Rosetta just normal M1 mac terminal ... I have set bash as default shell instead of their new zsh

```
git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

type git
git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)

osx 11.4
```

This is in a new mac M1 and I have not setup any git hooks ... in a separate copy of iTerm2 I did install Rosetta however this issue happened in a normal M1 iTerm2 terminal

Comment: Objective-C does dynamic dispatch for method calls; the error messages above are telling you that some bit of ObjC that Apple added to their Git build (standard Git builds don't directly use ObjC at all) is invoking a method that's defined in two separate libraries, and picking one of them at random. As long as both of them achieve the desired goal (whatever that may be), that won't be a problem; if one of them doesn't work, it's a problem, but not a *Git* problem since Git doesn't use ObjC itself.

Comment: Are there any hooks run when you do `git pull`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no I updated the post

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ? Even I get this when I run python3 command, but only once per login.

Comment: I have a similar issue when calling python3 I assume git calls python3 at some point. Is there any solution?